# How to access Azure Web App Container from Internet

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have created an Azure Webapp multi container service. It contains two containers, one for the client SPA web app, and one for an api, that the client webapp needs to call. The web app starts up, fine but I am not sure what url the webapp needs to use to call the api?

So what is the external url I need to use to access the api container?

Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  app:
  image: soxxxxdev.azurecr.io/soxxxale:latest
  ports:
   - 3009:3009
api:
  image: soxxxdev.azurecr.io/soxxxale-api:latest
  ports:
  - 4000:4000
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure App Service only exposes ports 80 and 443, so even though you can deploy a multi container app with Docker Compose it isn't suitable for what you are trying to achieve.

If you want to present a container that is exposing a different port then you can configure this using the `WEBSITES_PORT` application setting. But remember App Service only allows your container to expose only one port for HTTP requests.

Typically you would use multi container hosting for supporting services used by your application such as a database or Redis Cache (although not recommended in production), or to implement a sidecar pattern.

You would be better suited to host the API in the App Service, and host the SPA in either a storage account as a static web site, or using Azure Static Web Apps.

**App Service Ports**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features

**WEBSITES_PORT**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-port-number

**Multi Container**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-multi-container

**Sidecar Pattern**: [Differences between Sidecar and Ambassador and Adapter pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451056/differences-between-sidecar-and-ambassador-and-adapter-pattern)

**Static Web Hosting**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

**Azure Static Web Apps**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/static-web-apps/overview